# Why does this print 0 in toast message?

Tags: android, android-studio

Why does this return 0 ?

```
Toast.makeText(this, "" + 109 / (7 + 109) * 100, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When I try this on a calculator it outputs correctly, but the code prints 0. What is going wrong?

Thanks, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a casting issue. When you trying to do it all using integer it only converts to integer numbers. In the middle of this arithmetic operation, there was a middle state like `0.93 *100` but it is not the way when only integers are there. That 0.93 is rounded to `0` then it will multiply by `100` that's why this happened. Use below code to avoid that casting error. It implicitly bind with doubles

```
Toast.makeText(this, "" + 109.0 / (7.0 + 109.0)*100 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Nice to hear it. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

using calculator answer is 0.93 but using round finger last number is  3<5 then value of 0 will always 0 so it will multiply by 0*100 then answer will 0

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is ensure the numbers in the operation are float, and then to control how many decimals to print use the String.Format method. In the example is set to 0 decimals (**%.0f**):

```
String value = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.0f", 109.0f / (7.0f + 109.0f) * 100.0f);
Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```